# How to make background image fit properly in scroll view?

Tags: swift, background, uiscrollview, scrollview

The scaleAspectfit seem to not be working. I'm trying to make my whole background image to fit slightly into the background, seeing more of the image. I've added a scroll view so users can scroll up and down a little bit to see the image.

However, my app is too zoomed into the image.

```
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentSize.height = 800
    view.bounces = true
    return view
}()
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "backgroundImage.png")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    scrollView.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    backgroundImage.center(x: scrollView.centerXAnchor, y: scrollView.centerYAnchor)


 }
```

// this is just the extension i'm using for autolayouts if you guys are wondering

```
extension UIView {

func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
    }

    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
    }

    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
    }

    if width != 0 {
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }

    if height != 0 {
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }

func center(x: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, y: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? ) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let x = x {
        centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: x).isActive = true
    }

    if let y = y {
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: y).isActive = true
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** you add the same imageView in 2 places here

```
view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

and here

```
scrollView.addSubview(backgroundImage)
```

so eventually it will be added only to the scrollView since it's one object

**Second** you need to constraint the imageView like this

```
backgroundImage.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, left: scrollView.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: scrollView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
```

and then according to scrollView content  the imageView will stretch

**Third** `contentMode` should be either

```
backgroundImage.contentMode =.scaleToFill // or .scaleAspectFill
```

Should mention that you can add the imageView to the `self.view` and make the scrollView background transparent to avoid losing quality and aspect of the imageView caused by stretching

Comment: I actually ended up scaling my pictures outside of swift to fit the app properly, but your answer helped me understand scrolling and views more. Thanks